# How to run CANVASENGINE server and physics world

Tags: node.js

Hi.

I'm using the framework **canvasengine** with **node.js**. I'm also using **box2d** framework (physic engine).

The problem is that I have my **canvasengine** framework running (so it's waiting for connections). I want to run an infinite loop which is stepping the physics world (world.step(fps, iterations)), but it seems that threads aren't existent in node.js. So, how can i accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){world.step()},1000/60)
```

should step your world at 60 fps

Answer (score 1):

More recent browsers have a function called window.requestAnimationFrame.
This function is used to make smooth animations inside the browser.
For a safe implementation of the function (you can run it everywhere), take a look at this piece of code:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
};
```

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is a great thing, and it absolutely should be used, but it's best if you know exactly why and when to use it. From a render loop it's perfect, but when stepping through a physics simulation you might find it better to go with setInterval. Decoupling  your simulation from your rendering allows you to adjust the rate of simulation, giving you the option to slow down or speed up the game without affecting the render rate. Different programs will have different needs, of course.